# Conditional Javascript redirect broken

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am using this script to redirect some visitors to my domain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = 'https://mydomain.com';
}
</script>
```

I don't know why it's not working - it seems to be ignoring the condition. This `<script>` tag is inside the page's `<head>` tag. How can I make this redirect work the way I want it to?

Comment: If you put an alert() inside of your if condition do you get the alert message? How about outside your if condition?

Comment: does your "if" condition satisfy, try console.log  inside your "if"

Comment: outside condition pop-up but when its inside it doesnt pop-up. Dont know why its ignoring that condition

Comment: try console.log(screen.width); outside your "if" condition and see what you get.

Comment: @TomasSmith - i think you tried all possible solutions but it is not working. there must be something else on the page which is not allowing your code to execute. Please try using `alert() ` and check properly where is the error

Comment: Did u checked your condition (screen.width >= 699) is true ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `window.location = 'https://mydomain.com';`

Comment: Is it going inside if loop, try to put alert('test') inside loop;

Comment: What I am saying is try if (screen.width <= 699) {
alert('test');} So, you will know whether it is going inside if loop or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think your screen size larger than 699. Check your computer screen size with this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = 'http://www.somedomain.com';
}
else
{
    alert(screen.width); // actual screen size
}
</script>
```

Comment: Seriously, are you kidding me??

Answer (score 0):

try putting it in the body, instead of the head

and use `window.location.href = 'URL';`